# How do I specify an image reference in a Drupal 8 REST POST request body?

Tags: media, 8

We have a content-type that includes a field of type Image.  There is also an image file that has been uploaded to Drupal.

We are trying to add new content via a Drupal 8 REST POST.  A new node is successfully created when the POST finishes, but the image field is never set.  Here is what we are trying:

POST to:   http:///entity/node?_format=hal_json

The normal 4 headers are set

POST Body:

```
{
    "_links": {
    "type": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8087/rest/type/node/product"
    }
  },
    "title": [{"value":"ProductC"}],
    "field_description": [{"value":"ProductC Description"}],
    "field_product_image": [{"src":"/sites/default/files/2017-03/samplelogo_1.jpeg"}],
    "field_product_name": [{"value":"ProductCName"}],
    "field_product_n": [{"value":"prodC"}]
}
```

Any pointers on how to construct the "field_product_image" line in the payload to link the image to new content node?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `target_id` instead of `src` and using the File ID as the value instead?

Comment: I had tried target_id before, but used the entire URL for the image.  I tried again with just the image ID, and it worked perfectly.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

> I tried again with just the image ID, and it worked perfectly. Thanks
>   very much!

To elaborate...

After the image file has been created in Drupal, and you have the File ID you'll be ready to create/update Nodes. Instead of setting the `src` value on the image field you just need to set the `target_id` value.

Change this:

```
"field_product_image": [{"src":"/sites/default/files/2017-03/samplelogo_1.jpeg"}],
```

To something like this:

```
"field_product_image": [{"target_id": 123}],
```

If you're using JavaScript this would typically be accomplished with 2 async calls. The first call would POST the binary file data to Drupal (or base 64 encoded string) to obtain the File ID, the second call (which takes places in the "success" callback of the first call) would then be used to create/update the node's image field with the new File ID.

The following d.o issue is an important one to follow and is very much related to the Question: https://www.drupal.org/node/1927648